# Set default date insted of current date in evo-calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Flexible Event Calendar In jQuery - evo-calendar - How to set default selected date instead of current date.

```js
$('#demoEvoCalendar').evoCalendar({
  todayHighlight:false,
  selectDate:"09/10/2020",
  format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
  titleFormat: "MM",
  sidebarToggler: true,
  sidebarDisplayDefault: false,
  eventListToggler: false,
  eventDisplayDefault: false,
  calendarEvents: [ ]
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? May you show that?

Comment: Looking at [their documentation](https://edlynvillegas.github.io/evo-calendar/) you may have to use the method `selectDate` once the calendar has been initialised as there does not seem to be a way to configure it in the settings.

Comment: Consider editing the question?

Comment: `selectDate` is a method, not a setting. `$("#evoCalendar").evoCalendar('selectDate', '09/10/2020');`

Answer (score 0):

use `selectDate` inside `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#demoEvoCalendar').evoCalendar({
    todayHighlight:false,
    ...
  });

  $("#evoCalendar").evoCalendar('selectDate', "February/15/2020"); //replace date here
})
```